# Invalid function return

Tags: python, recursion

This is my code, why when i print(is_happy(13)) i got True, but in the result of happy_numbers i don't get 13 and many correct numbers?

```
def is_happy(n, result = []):
    next_number = sum(map(lambda x: int(x) ** 2, str(n)))
    if next_number == 1:
        return True
    elif next_number in result:
        return False
    else:
        result.append(next_number)
        return is_happy(next_number)

def happy_numbers(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if is_happy(i):
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Also [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) for more info on how to debug

Comment: It also helps to extract a [mcve] and not post partial code as above, leaving us to guess how that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using [a mutable default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) in `is_happy(n, result=[])`. This means that the `result` won't start as an empty list every time it's run but rather will keep its old results.

To counter this, I'd remove the default argument and explicitly pass the array:

```
def is_happy(n, result):
  # all the stuff you already had
      return is_happy(next_number, result)
```

and in the other function

```
if is_happy(i, []):
```

Answer (score 0):

Generators make your programs easier to write -

```py
def is_happy(n, seen = set()):
  if n == 1:
    return True
  elif n in seen:
    return False
  else:
    return is_happy(sum(x ** 2 for x in digits(n)), seen | {n})
```

```py
def digits(n):
  if n < 10:
    yield n
  else:
    yield from digits(n // 10)
    yield n % 10
```

```py
def happy_numbers(n):
  for x in range(n):
    if is_happy(x):
      yield x
```

```py
print(list(happy_numbers(100)))
```

`is_happy` can be optimized with [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) -

```py
from functools import lru_cache
seen = set()

@lru_cache
def is_happy(n):
  if n == 1:
    return True
  elif n in seen:
    return False
  else:
    seen.add(n)
    answer = is_happy(sum(x ** 2 for x in digits(n)))
    seen.remove(n)
    return answer
```

```py
print(list(happy_numbers(10000)))
```

|  | before optimization | with LRU cache |
| --- | --- | --- |
| real | 1,303 ms | 284 ms |
| user | 470 ms | 118 ms |
| sys | 19 ms | 13 ms |